# Flat ui proをインストールするとconflictになる項目がある

Tags: ruby-on-rails

flat ui proを [reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails](https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails)を使ってRails4.2のプロジェクトにインストールしようとしています。
インストール中にconflictになってしまう項目があるのですがなぜそうなるのでしょうか？

```
maimai-no-MacBook-Air:ponpon mai$ bin/rails generate flatuipro:install ~/Desktop/flat-ui-pro
       exist  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/javascripts

       exist  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less


    conflict  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/glyphicons.less
Overwrite /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/glyphicons.less? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
       force  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/glyphicons.less

    conflict  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/local-fonts.less
Overwrite /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/local-fonts.less? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
       force  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/local-fonts.less

    conflict  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/variables.less
Overwrite /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/variables.less? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
       force  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/variables.less
       exist  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/fonts

       exist  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/images

    conflict  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/index.html
Overwrite /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/index.html? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
       force  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/index.html
    conflict  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/docs.less
Overwrite /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/docs.less? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
       force  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/docs.less
   identical  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/prettyprint.less
   identical  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/docs.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/flatuipro.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/flatuipro.less
        gsub  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/variables.less
        gsub  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/local-fonts.less
        gsub  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/less/modules/glyphicons.less
        gsub  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/docs.less
        gsub  /Users/mai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/app/assets/demo/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails generate flatuipro:install <flatuipro_dir>` は、必要なファイルを `<flatuipro_dir>` から **gem 自身の** `app/assets` にコピーします。

[designmodo-flatuipro-rails/install_generator.rb at master · reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails](https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/flatuipro/install/install_generator.rb)

gem を再インストールすることなく `flatuipro:install` を複数回実行すると、同じ場所に同じファイルをコピーしようとしますが、前回 `flatuipro:install` した内容から `<flatuipro_dir>` 側が更新されていた場合、　conflict ということになるかと思います。

というあたりで心当たりはあるでしょうか？

Comment: こころあたりがありました。
意味を理解することができました。ありがとうございます。